# Replacing a reoccurring value in a string with random values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
Today is a sunny day
```

I would like to take the `is` and replace that with three random terms.

So: `Today {was|wasn't|isn't} a sunny day`

However, if `is` is in another string with five occurrences (say an article), I would like to replace each occurrence with a random value from `{was|wasn't|isn't}`

How can I accomplish this?

So far, I know you must use str_replace, with an array inside a foreach loop. However I can't get it working.

Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification:
If the string contains 'is' less than 5 times, then replace with the whole block of all 3. If 'is' is found >= 5 times, then just randomly choose one of the 3 instead of replacing it with the block of 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$replacements = array("was", "wasn't", "isn't");
preg_replace("/\wis\w/e", "$replacements[array_rand($replacements)]", $text);
```

The 'e' modifier in the searched regular expression causes the replacement string to be evaluated as PHP code. array_rand is then used to pick a random key from $replacements

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way...

```
$str = "Today is a sunny day";
$findme = "is";
$arr = array("was","wasn't","isn't");
 $tmp = explode("is",$str);
 $str = $tmp[0];
 for($i=1;$i<count($tmp);$i++)
    $str .= array_rand($arr) . $tmp[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

See this wack solution here

```
$d = array("was","wasn't","isn't");
$st = "Today is a sunny day, is it not?";
$arr = explode(" ", $st);



        for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
             if ($arr[$i] == "is"){
             $r =  rand(0, 2);
             $arr[$i] = $d[$r];
        }
        }

foreach($arr as $v){

    echo $v." ";
}

?>
```

Outputs

```
Today wasn't a sunny day, was it not?
```